# How to add toolbar above text in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I wan to add interaction with text items in flutter. For eg on selecting the selected text need to be have a highlighted colour and there is a tooltip need to be shown on top. And when user clicks anywhere outside the highlight need to disappear. I am not sure how to configure that in flutter web.
For eg in medium

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom class for Controls you need. Extend the Custom Class with `MaterialTextSelectionControls` class

I think this Medium Article has the thing you need. [Check this Link](https://ktuusj.medium.com/flutter-custom-selection-toolbar-3acbe7937dd3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this third party lib for this https://pub.dev/packages/selectable

Simply wrap your text widgets inside seletable and pass pop menu item to show toolbar option. Here is an example for its usage:

```
    Selectable(
      popupMenuItems: [SelectableMenuItem(type: SelectableMenuItemType.copy),],
      child: Text(
        'This text is wrapped in an Selectable widget, so it is selectable.',
        style: textStyle2,
      ),
    ),
```