# Flutter: Make text/images selectable in whole web app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-text

In the Flutter web apps, there is no default functionality which makes text and images in the app selectable.

**Is there a way to enable selection functionality for text/image on web?**

I did check `SelectableText` widget but it is only for text and I would need to use it over every text. Also, you can't select text in multiple `SelectableText` widgets at once, you can only select text in one of them. I'm looking for a solution to select all text in the app without making change to every text widget.

Let me know if there’s one step solution to achieve this thing in whole web app.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Flutter 3.3, with the introduction of the `SelectionArea` widget, any child of the `SelectionArea` widget has selection enabled for free!

[image]

To take advantage of this powerful new feature, simply wrap your route body (such as the `Scaffold`) with the `SelectionArea` widget and let Flutter do the rest.

For a more comprehensive deep dive into this awesome new feature, please visit the [`SelectionArea` API page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectionArea-class.html).

Comment: Is there a way to display toolbar above the selected text ? My text widgets are wrapped inside selection Area. I tried using selectable text for this same beahviour but it seems toolbar is not available in flutter web

Comment: My query is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72747672/how-to-add-toolbar-above-text-in-flutter-web

Comment: Thank you for this, it's pretty straightforward. Do you know the reason why text is not selectable by default? Does the use of this widget affect performance in any way?

Comment: Can it be used as a SEO solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Web currently does not support multiple text selection across SelectableText widgets.

However, there are some experimental widgets that people are currently working on. According to a guide available at:

[Custom SelectableScope Widget](https://flutterrepos.com/lib/wilsonowilson-better_selection)

They have proposed a custom widget, a Selectable scope, which basically allows for anything within it to be selectable (currently text and images)

**NOTE:** THIS IS CURRENTLY UNDER EXPERIMENTATION AND MIGHT CHANGE AS MENTIONED IN THE PROVIDED LINK.

Comment: Yeah. I did check this earlier but I'm looking for something stable as our app is live and one step solution as this way I would still need to change every text widget in my app.

Comment: I see. A little digging up in the Flutter official Github repo led me to this widget, on which documentation currently seems to be non-existent as it was recently added. 

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/15aa3bfda3658d1094ae50cc4c608fc94642405a/examples/api/lib/material/selection_area/selection_area.dart

Apparently this widget supports what you are trying to achieve. However, this again isn't available in the stable version of Flutter and is currently under development. 

Your best bet right now would be to go with something that works until this gets added to the stable branch.

Comment: ahan, i see. seems like until this feature comes in stable I might use that custom `SelectableScope` widget. Btw thank you for your response!